# Java servlets: How to detect (on Server Side) if JavaScript (on Client Side) has beeen tampered with?

Tags: java, javascript, html, security, validation

This is a very general question, but please bear with me ...
I have recently put alot of effort in form validation javascript, before submitting forms to my server, then the idea hit me ... I have countless times viewed the source of websites to find how things work. Also we all know that although we could not change JavaScript, but when it comes to form validation, we can set a break-point before the validation script runs, change the div/input tag id/class that is to be validated, then put it back to its original name after stepping through the validation steps and before submitting the form.

Then it hit me that I might have to re validate everything on server side AGAIN ... Each time.

Here is the question, how do I make sure, or at least detect that my JavaScript/HTML has been debugged/ source-viewed/ tampered with?

Thanks alot!!

Initial thoughts on the subject:
Maybe a check sum of the entire loaded document (js files, html) to be submitted along with the form, or through an ajax post prior to submitting, but that wont hinder a seasoned programmed very much.

Comment: _"Then it hit me that I might have to re validate everything on server side"_ - Yes. Except it's not "might have to", it is _will_ have to. You don't need some elaborate "have they tampered" test though, you just have to validate the actual submitted data.

Comment: Thats not the point ... There are consequences to knowing if the served page has been "Used as is" or someone checked/changed the inside workings of it ... re validation usually comes in the last steps of development (as far as I am concerned) thus it would be nice to avoid it altogether for non-sensitive cases, specially if my forms are generally large and frequently used (basically migrating a company to go online, so imagine an entire office going paperless) ... it would cut down billing on GAE run time ... thats all, no harm in asking !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, it's not possible. Even if you send a checksum with the form, the user can change the checksum before submitting. The only way is to revalidate everything server side, and never trust something coming from the client.

Comment: Thanks !! That was fast !! So whats the point of the whole JS validation libraries growing like wild fire if its all gonna be done again anyway ?? Man the level that browsers are at right now is just un acceptable !! We need a sever make over ASAP !!

Comment: @a.atlam The point of all the JS validation libraries is to give a nice real-time feedback to the user without needing a round-trip to the server. But, security-wise, they are useless, you still have to validate everything on server-side. Some projects (like https://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/ ) aims at sharing the validation logic between the client and the server, but I'm not aware of some standard way of doing it.